# Update helm chart values for different environments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have helm charts created for a microservice that I have built and everything is working as expected. Now, I have created a new k8s namespace and I want to try to deploy the same helm charts as my old namespace. Although, I have just one value that I need it different while everything else remain the same.

Do I have to create another values.yaml for the new namespace and copy everything over and update the one field I want updated ? Or is there any other way ? I do not want to use the --set method of passing updates to the command line.

Comment: You could also use `helm install -f more-values.yaml`; that YAML file would override anything in the chart's `values.yaml`.

Comment: @DavidMaze When you say override values.yaml, does that mean it overrides any tokens that matches or the entire file just gets overridden ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David suggested the right way. You can use different `values.yaml` where you can specify the namespace you want to deploy the chart:

```
$ helm install -f another-namespace-values.yaml <my-release> .
```

It's also entirely possible to launch helm chart with multiple values.
For more reading please check [values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) section of helm docs.